# Reading a .txt file into JAR. It works in Eclipse but not in exported JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, resources

I am aware that this question has been asked a hundred times before but nothing I have tried seems to work.

I just want to be able to load a text file into a JAR. Most methods I have tried work fine in Eclipse but not once it is exported. Here is some of the code I have tried below:

```
public String[] loadTranslations(String trans){

    String name = "/translations/"+trans+".txt";

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
      URL url = this.getClass().getResource(name);
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        File f = new File(url.getFile());

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);        
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                 String line = null;
                 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                     lines.add(line);

                 }
                 bufferedReader.close();
                 return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException notFoundEx) {
            System.out.println("Caught FileNotFoundException: " + notFoundEx.getMessage());
        }

        return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

and ...

```
public String[] loadTranslations3(String trans){
    String name = "translations/"+trans+".txt";
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines.toArray(new String[0]);

    }
```

The function should be run by a command such as

```
String[] translations = loadTranslations("EN");
```

I have tried with/without slashes etc.

I have my translations folder in the src directory and it is included in build path:
[image: Folder]

The Exception is a NullPOinter:
[image: Null]

And this is the dump when I try to run the second code example:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at com.animation.shop.Main.loadTranslations(Main.java:215)
at com.animation.shop.Main.initTranslations(Main.java:287)
at com.animation.shop.Main.initVars(Main.java:197)
at com.animation.shop.Main.<init>(Main.java:1142)
at com.animation.shop.Main$1.run(Main.java:361)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatc...
```

Line 215:

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)));
```

Comment: When you are exporting the jar, do you include the translations folder as part of the export?

Comment: when you say "not working"- what do you mean?

Comment: @Java sorry, It's a null pointer exception. I've included a screenshot from ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @Aritra: The folder is visible in the JAR (I think by including it in build in Eclipse handles that part)

Comment: also can you show the structure of your jar file?

Comment: 216:  File f = new File(url.getFile());

Comment: @Java: The translations folder is in the root directory of the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Still not too sure what the problem was there, probably something I overlooked but I got it working the by using the processing.core.PApplet loadStrings() function:
Code:(basicPapplet extends processing.core.PApplet)

```
    public String[] loadTranslations(String trans){

    String name = "data/translations/"+trans+".txt";

     basicPapplet bp = new basicPapplet();
```

return  bp.loadStrings(name);

```
}
```

Comment: @Aritra I assume at this point, any answer is desired. You cannot be picky when answers you see online do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is working just fine. Here's how I made it work:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        String[] strings = test.loadTranslations3("test");
        for(String someString : strings) {
            System.out.println(someString);
        }
    }

    public String[] loadTranslations3(String trans) {
        String name = "translations/" + trans + ".txt";
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```

My folder structure in eclipse is:

```
src/somepackage/Test.java
src/translations/test.txt
```

When you export this from Eclipse, export as a Runnable JAR file, and point to the Test.java class.

Also, make sure in your project properties, the src folder has:

```
Included: (All)
Excluded:(None)
```